# can not add text box input in table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code :

http://plnkr.co/edit/RqLurBaCsgjQjOYMtl8r?p=preview

here there is a textbox and when user add something to the textbox and push add button then the entered text should be added to the table Here is my javaScript code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('Service', function() {
    var typesHash = [ {
        id : '1',
        name : 'lemon',
        price : 100,
        unit : 2.5
    }, {
        id : '2',
        name : 'meat',
        price : 200,
        unit : 3.3
    } ];
    var service = {
        addTable : addTable,
        getData : getData,


    };
    return service;
    function addTable(data) {

        typesHash.push(data);
    }
    function getData() {
        return typesHash;
    }
});
app.controller('table', function(Service) {
    //get the return data from getData funtion in factory
    this.typesHash = Service.getData();
    this.testData = {
        id : '1',
        name : "test",
        price : 100,
        unit : 2.5
    };
    //get the addtable function from factory 
    this.addTable = Service.addTable;
});
```

here as far as testData is static as follow it works:

```
this.testData = {
        id : '1',
        name : "test",
        price : 100,
        unit : 2.5
    };
```

but here the text in the textbox is not added so I changed the above code as follow:

```
this.testData = {
        id : '1',
        name : $("#txt").val(),
        price : 100,
        unit : 2.5
    };
```

the name gets nothing and row is added but name spot is empty?

Just a quick note that this is a simpler version of my real code and I have a reason to use factory. 
Can ahyone help me to find out why this table does not connect to textbox correctly?

Comment: use `ng-model` to bind the input to a scope object. You don't use `value` on inputs in angular. If you want to learn agular...take jQuery.js out of the page, until you need something like a plugin that can't be done using angular

Comment: I answered below also on a side note you may want to check out angular-x-editable as it helps with this whole editable table business... I've had pretty good success mixing ng-table for the sorting/paging/headers and angular-x-editable for a cancel-able edit/save option.  Also agree with the comment above, leave the jQuery behind if you can or just learn to write directives and only use it in there where DOM manipulation is expected, you'll probably find that the built in directives and third party ones cover most of what you want to do already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified version of the plnkr (ooo nice design changes SO).

**Updated** pasted a bad plnkr link before.
http://plnkr.co/edit/4g7LGRLBNEH2LeuEm1qN?p=preview

code from the post, let me know if this doesn't cover some scenario you were imagining.  I tried getting rid of all the style cruft, that should be done in CSS or using things like text-right or text-center provided by bootstrap.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.factory('Service', function() {
        var typesHash = [ {
            id :1,
            name : 'lemon',
            price : 100,
            unit : 2.5
        }, {
            id : 2,
            name : 'meat',
            price : 200,
            unit : 3.3
        } ];

        var localId = 3;

        var service = {
            addTable : addTable,
            getData : getData,


        };
        return service;
        function addTable(name) {
            typesHash.push({id:localId++, name:name, price:100,unit:1});
        }
        function getData() {
            return typesHash;
        }
    });
    app.controller('table', function(Service) {
        //get the return data from getData funtion in factory
        this.typesHash = Service.getData();
        //get the addtable function from factory 
        this.addTable = Service.addTable;
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="table as tableTools">
    <form>
      <div class="row commonRow">
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-right">
          item:
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <input id="txt" type="text" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="tableTools.inputData" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="tableTools.addTable(tableTools.inputData);tableTools.inputData=''">
                click me
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </form>

    <div class="row commonRow">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>item</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody ng-controller="table as iterateTb">
            <tr ng-repeat="x in iterateTb.typesHash track by x.id">
              <td>
                <div>{{x.name}}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="x.name"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the updated plunker :-

http://plnkr.co/edit/uDIEAjRtpM7MnQu72LAA?p=preview

I just added `data.name=$("#txt").val();` before pushing the data into array.

```
    function addTable(data) {
data.name=$("#txt").val();
            typesHash.push(data);
        }
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: @charlietfl what is your suggestion?

Comment: `ng-model` is the proper way. It 2 way binds data with the scope

Comment: @charlietfl can you give a sample code for that I could not make it work that way

Comment: @charlietfl i m agree with you its not a angular way we should have to use $scope.model for this but it is just a hack to solve the problem.

Comment: well it didn't say *this is a hack*. People don't learn when bad habits get perpetuated do they?

Comment: Actually when i first looked at the code I was thinking about the same. I was trying to find the angular way but i couldn't.
So sorry for this but if i will find something i will update it.

Comment: And we cannot use ng-model because that input is outside the scope of controller :-p